# Using Google App Script to get values from sheets and display them in text box

Tags: javascript, debugging, search, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So, Google recently updated Google App Script API and added lots of nice features, however, in the process, they also depreciated LOTS of API. I have been working on a Library Database user interface for the place I work on my college campus, and when I wanted to update my app to the new API, a lot of things broke, and I can't figure out how to make them work again.

What I am trying to do is get a value from a Google Sheets file, and simply put that value in a text box on the web app. Currently I cannot get that work work. In addition, I discovered something that was troublesome, and that is, the debugger seems to not be correct. I know, bold accusation. Let me try to show you.

Code.gs

```
  function doGet(e) {

  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index')
  .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);

  return html; 
}


function searchBooks(searchItem, searchType){
  var sI = searchItem;
  Logger.log(sI);
  var sT = searchType;
  Logger.log(sT);
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  var ss = sheets[0];
  var itemDataRange = ss.getRangeByName("itemInformation");
  var selectedItem = null; //the item that will be returned
  //var selectedSearch = searchItem;
  var titles = sheet.getRange("K2:K9507").getValues(); //get the titles of the items
  var authors = sheet.getRange("J2:J9507").getValues(); //get the authors in the sheet
  var barcodes = sheet.getRange("B2:B9507").getValues(); //get the barcodes in the sheet
  var itemsArray = new Array();


  if (sT == '')
  {
   return null; 
  }
  else if (sT.value == 'Please select type...')
  {
    var test = "this works";
    Logger.log(test);
    return selectedItem;
  }
  else if(sT == 'Barcode')
  {
    var selectedBarcode = sI;

    for(var i = 0; i < barcodes.length; i++) //search for the barcode
    {
      if(barcodes[i] == selectedBarcode)
      {
        selectedItem = titles[i];
        break; //break immediately because barcodes are not duplicated
      }
    }

    if(selectedItem != null)
    {
      return selectedItem;
    }
    else
    {
      selectedItem = "No book(s) found";
      return selectedItem;
    }
    return selectedItem;
        } 
    }  
    ...
```

index.html

```
<script>


function bookSearch()
{
   var searchItem = String(document.getElementById('searchItem').value.toLowerCase());
   var searchType = String(document.getElementById('searchType').value.toLowerCase());
   google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(bookFound).searchBooks(searchItem, searchType);

}

...

function bookFound(selectedItem)
{

   document.getElementById("bookResultBox").innHTML = selectedItem;
   alert(selectedItem);
}
</script>
```

When I test this code, and put a search value with the category "Barcodes" selected, I successfully get console logs of the data being brought into the function searchBooks, however the debug console says that the variables sI, sT, searchItems, and searchType are all undefined.

I've also been having trouble trying to figure out the proper API calls to use to search through the spreadsheet (when dealing with stuff like getRangeByName). I think there might be a slightly different way to do this since the big update. I may have had it working before I changed some of the code, although I started changing a lot of it when I was trying to figure out WHY nothing was displaying. When I saw at the "undefined" debug console logs, it scared me a bit. I can't tell if I'm messing up, or the API is messing up.

Any help is much appreciated in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

There's probably an error in your code.  It's probably coming from line:

```
var itemDataRange = ss.getRangeByName("itemInformation");
```

Your variable `ss` is not a **spreadsheet** class, it's a **sheet** class.  You can't get a **RangeByName** of a sheet class.  There is no `getRangeByName()` method of the **Sheet** class.

I'd change your code to this:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var itemDataRange = ss.getRangeByName("itemInformation");
```

If you need to get the first sheet:

```
var theFirstSheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
```

Comment: Hm. This will definitely help for when the search is actually triggered, however I can't seem to get the search conditional to trigger. I'm playing with it right now and even trying to trigger the search conditional with a blank text box and the search type set to "Please Select Type..." will not trigger anything. It should be triggering the first "else if" , so I put a Logger.log within that conditional and I'm not even getting a confirmation  log in the console.

I am however getting logs from when the function searchBooks is called, and the searchItem and searchType are infact being read in

Comment: If you aren't familiar with the debugger, learn how to use that:  [Google Documentation - Troubleshooting](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting#using_the_debugger_and_breakpoints)

Comment: As mentioned in the original post, I have been trying to, but for some odd reason the debugger is telling me that nothing is stored in these two variables, even though the console log is printing their values out just fine. I don't know which to believe :(

Comment: Maybe try to decrease the row size for testing.  Looks like you are getting almost ten thousand rows.

Comment: hmm yeah Ill give that a shot, it'll definitely make it easier to test, even if it doesn't immediately solve it.